# Generate Reports from the survey application developed from the SP 2013 OOTB template.

Tags: 2013, reports, survey

I've created a survey application using the SP 2013 OOTB template.  How do I access the data to generate reports?

Answer (score 0):

While viewing the survey list, you can use the Export to Excel or Open With Access options on the ribbon.  This will let you create reports with those tools.  If you we're looking for something else, post what reporting tools you were wanting to use.